# App to keep a list of my repetoire (as a folk muscian)

Tags: music

As a folk musician, I am looking for an (Android and Desktop) app that I can use to keep track of all the tunes that I know. I've been using Evernote recently which was been decent, but their free version is limited and I'm looking for alternatives. I need it to be able to keep a large list of tunes, (the notes in Evernote) that have a title, the ability to contain text (for information on the tunes) and attachments like images, PDFs (sheet music) and recordings. Ideally I'd also want to tag the tunes and be able to access them offline. I understand that essentially Evernote Plus does all this, but surely there are other musicians who have encountered the same problem and a more specicialised app has been made for it?

Here is a screenshot of what my Evernote currently looks like.[image]